# Solve and Reduce with Log finding unexpected root

Tags: equation-solving

We give equations like $\ln(1-x)-\ln(x-2)=0$ to our calculus students. This equation clearly has no solution, since $\ln(1-x)$ is only defined if $x<1$ and $\ln(x-2)$ only if $x>2$.

Still, the *Mathematica* input

```
Solve[Log[1 - x] - Log[x - 2] == 0, x]
```

gives

> ```
>  {{x -> 3/2}}
> ```

Also,

```
Reduce[Log[1 - x] - Log[x - 2] == 0, x]
```

gives

> ```
> x == 3/2.
> ```

Since *Mathematica* uses the principal branch, this should not happen.

I *guess* that Mathematica first simplifies the equation to

$\quad \quad \ln\frac{1-x}{x-2}=0$

Now, $\tfrac{1-x}{x-2}>0$ for $1<x<2$, and $x=3/2$ really solves this last equation.

Thus, my question boils down to: Shouldn't *Mathematica* test if its solution really solves the original equation given by the user?

Comment: Hi @mickep, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. [Your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), but its a good idea to wait a few hour for other answers before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you.

Comment: Hi @rhermans. Thank you for your suggestion, I will follow your advice next time. In this case, I understand what Mathematica does and even if I don't agree with its choice (of defining the argument/logarithm on the negative real axis and thus making it a non-continuous function), I'm now fully aware of it.

Comment: When there are no undefined parameters, and input is not explicitly polynomial, `Solve` does in fact test solutions. That's the option `VerifySolutions -> Automatic` at work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, both $(1-x)$ and $(x-2)$ evaluate to $-1/2$ when  $x\rightarrow 3/2$, and `Log[-1/2]` its well defined in the complexes, for instance $e^{iπ}= −1$, implies that $\ln(−1)=i π$, and therefore `Log[-1/2]= I π - Log[2]` so you are subtracting two well defined identical complex numbers to get zero. Therefore, this solutions does really solve the original equation, in the complex domain.

If you want to force a restriction, you can specify the domain where [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) should look for the solution. *i.e.* `Complexes`, `Reals`, `Integers` or `Rationals`.

```
Solve[Log[1 - x] - Log[x - 2] == 0, x, Complexes]
```

> {{x -> 3/2}}

```
Solve[Log[1 - x] - Log[x - 2] == 0, x, Reals]
```

> {}

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Thus, I just learned that Mathematica actually is not giving something undefined along the branch cut of the logarithm, but rather uses $\log(x)=\ln(-x)+i\pi$ for $x<0$.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, Mathematica is assuming a complex valued logarithm (and hence can take negative inputs).

If you query this on Wolfram Alpha ([here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=Log%5B1%20-%20x%5D%20-%20Log%5Bx%20-%202%5D%20%3D%3D%200)) you can see the pod clarifies the solution is assuming this complex valued logarithm:

[image]